# New 'Similar questions' box is too small

Tags: feature-request, design, asking-questions, similar-questions

I noticed there's a new 'Similar questions' box now. I remember that with the old box I could see about three questions at once, here I can see only one and a small portion of another.

[image]

Could this be re-made to display more info?

Comment: Better yet, make it resizable (e.g., by making the split draggable).

Comment: An option to show just the response count and title would show more matches in less space

Comment: If only some people typed their question in the search bar before the title.

Comment: Which brings up a good point, make the search bar show auto-results.

Comment: @Jab Interestingly, the search algorithm used by this box is considered by many to be more effective at finding duplicates (or at least related questions) than the normal site search.

Comment: That's what I meant. Implement the same or similar variant  into the normal site search.

Comment: @CodyGray Do you as well consider it to be more effective?